# Geodjango. Distance beetwen two points in one SQL query

Tags: python, django, orm, geodjango

I have a task to find the nearest town to the apartment. I suppose it is not difficult task, but I'm new in GeoDjango so every anwser will help :)
I have to use only one SQL query. Using django ORM of course.

```
from django.contrib.gis.db.models import MultiPolygonField, PointField
from django.db import models


class City(models.Model):
    geo_area = MultiPolygonField(verbose_name='Area')
    center = PointField(verbose_name='center of City')


class Flat(models.Model):
    geo_point = PointField(verbose_name='Coordinates of apartment')

def distance_from_city(self):
    """
    Method calculating distance to the nearest town. 
    In the case where the coordinates of the apartments are located
    in the middle of the city, it counts the distance to the center 
    of the city (City.center) otherwise has the distance to the border 
    town (City.geo_area) closest to the coordinates of the apartment.
    The distance is returned in kilometers
    """
    pass
```

Comment: Have you already tried something, though? Some code would help understanding the problem.

Comment: I don't know about geodjango but geopy can do this for you. See the examples: https://github.com/geopy/geopy

Comment: "I have to use only one SQL query" why? what's wrong with using two queries? This can be done with single query yes but it's a lot of toasted brain cells.